# Downloading multiple files using Dio Package in Flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, async-await, dio

I am trying to download multiple files using dio package. From this [git issue](https://github.com/flutterchina/dio/issues/268) I found out that future.wait can be used to achieve this task, though I am able to update multiple files concurrently but cannot update the database. Here's the downloading code snippet

```
  download(Attachment attachment) => work(context, () async {
        final dio = Dio();
        final path = await getLocalFilePath(attachment);
        var downloadRequest = dio.download(
          attachment.url,
          path,
          deleteOnError: true,
          onReceiveProgress: (count, total) {
            setState(
              () {
                _downloadProgress[attachment.url] = count / total;
                print(_downloadProgress[attachment.url]);
              },
            );
          },
        ).then(
          (value) async {
            await ReviewDownloadsDB().add({
              'id': attachment.id,
              'name': attachment.name,
              'url': attachment.url,
              'path': path
            });
          },
        );
        Future.wait([downloadRequest]);
      });
```

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong and how can I add the downloaded item to my ObjectDB database after it's downloaded. The complete Code for the screen is present [here](https://pastebin.com/kK0B4Rfq).

Comment: Have you found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using a different package, you can use [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) package to download multiple files concurrently. The default max number of concurrent download tasks set is three(3), you can change this config by following this [guide](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader#configure-maximum-number-of-concurrent-download-tasks).

You can then use `FlutterDownloader.enqueue()` to create download tasks.

```dart
final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
  url: 'your download link',
  headers: {}, // optional: header send with url (auth token etc)
  savedDir: 'the path of directory where you want to save downloaded files',
  showNotification: true, // show download progress in status bar (for Android)
  openFileFromNotification: true, // click on notification to open downloaded file (for Android)
);
```